# Custom visualforce page to upload lage video file from Salesforce to GoogleDrive

Tags: apex, visualforce, api, integration, callout

I want to upload large videos using the custom Visualforce page. But it is showing the following error while I am uploading the video - "String length exceeds maximum: 6000000

**Error is in expression '{!UploadFile}' in component  in page googledrive: Class.GoogleDriveController1.UploadFile: line 57, column 1" ---An unexpected error has occurred. Your development organization has been notified.**

Kindly provide me a feasible solution where I can upload the video from Salesforce to Google Drive. 
My Visualforce page is -

```
<apex:page controller="GoogleDriveController1">
<style>
    .error {
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    color: orange;
    }

    .myClass {
    color: black !important;
    background: orange !important;
    width: 300px;
    font-size: 20px !important;
    height: 35px;
    }
</style>
<center>
    <apex:form style="margin-top:5%;margin-left:5%;width:60%">
        <apex:pageblock >
            <apex:commandbutton styleClass="myClass" onclick="this.value = 'Authenticating....'" action="{!DriveAuth}" value="Google Drive Authentication">
            </apex:commandbutton>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <apex:inputfile value="{!file}" contentType="{!filetype}" filename="{!filename}" />
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <apex:commandButton styleClass="myClass" onclick="this.value = 'Uploading...'" value="Upload file" action="{!UploadFile}" />
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <apex:messages styleClass="error" />
            <br/>
        </apex:pageblock>
    </apex:form>
</center>
```

Here is my Apex Class-

```
public class GoogleDriveController1 {
private String code;
public boolean val {
    get;
    set;
}
public blob file {
    get;
    set;
}
public String filetype {
    get;
    set;
}
public String filename {
    get;
    set;
}
private string key = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx';
private string secret = 'xxxxxxxxxx';
private string redirect_uri = 'https://xxx.my.salesforce.com/apex/GoogleDrive';

private String accesstoken;
private Integer expiresIn;
private String tokentype;
public GoogleDriveController1() {
    code = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('code');
    //Get the access token once we have code
    if (code != '' && code != null) {
        AccessToken();
      }
}
public PageReference DriveAuth() {
    //Authenticating
    PageReference pg = new PageReference(GoogleDriveAuthUri(key, redirect_uri));
    return pg;
}
public String GoogleDriveAuthUri(String Clientkey, String redirect_uri) {
    String key = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(Clientkey, 'UTF-8');
    String uri = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(redirect_uri, 'UTF-8');
    String authuri = '';
    authuri = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?' +
        'client_id=' + key +
        '&response_type=code' +
        '&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive' +
        '&redirect_uri=' + uri +
        '&state=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' +
        +
        'access_type=offline';
    return authuri;
}
public void UploadFile() {
    String boundary = '----------9889464542212';
    String delimiter = '\r\n--' + boundary + '\r\n';
    String close_delim = '\r\n--' + boundary + '--';
    String bodyEncoded = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(file);
    String body = delimiter + 'Content-Type: application/json\r\n\r\n' + '{ "title" : "' + filename + '",' + ' "mimeType" : "' + filetype + '" }' + delimiter + 'Content-Type: ' + filetype + '\r\n' + 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n' + '\r\n' + bodyEncoded + close_delim;
    Http http = new Http();
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setEndpoint('https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files?uploadType=multipart');
    req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken);
    req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/mixed; boundary="' + boundary + '"');
    req.setHeader('Content-length', String.valueOf(body.length()));
    req.setBody(body);
    req.setMethod('POST');
    req.setTimeout(60 * 1000);
    HttpResponse resp = http.send(req);
    file = null;
    filetype = '';
    filename = '';
}
public void AccessToken() {
    //Getting access token from google
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setMethod('POST');
    req.setEndpoint('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token');
    req.setHeader('content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    String messageBody = 'code=' + code + '&client_id=' + key + '&client_secret=' + secret + '&redirect_uri=' + redirect_uri + '&grant_type=authorization_code';
    req.setHeader('Content-length', String.valueOf(messageBody.length()));
    req.setBody(messageBody);
    req.setTimeout(60 * 1000);
    Http h = new Http();
    String resp;
    HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
    resp = res.getBody();
    JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(resp);
    while (parser.nextToken() != null) {
        if ((parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME)) {
            String fieldName = parser.getText();
            parser.nextToken();
            if (fieldName == 'access_token') {
                accesstoken = parser.getText();
            } else if (fieldName == 'expires_in') {
                expiresIn = parser.getIntegerValue();
            } else if (fieldname == 'token_type') {
                tokentype = parser.getText();
            }
        } }
    System.debug(' You can parse the response to get the access token ::: ' + resp);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

To upload files larger than six megabytes, you could use the [AJAX Proxy](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.ajax.meta/ajax/sforce_api_ajax_proxy.htm#!) in Visualforce. This will require re-implementing your logic in mostly JavaScript. However, unlike Apex, it has an unlimited payload size (I've tested over 100MB with this), so it should be able to handle whatever you want to throw at it.